# What is the most scenic route to drive from San Francisco to North Rim

Tags: usa, driving, san-francisco, grand-canyon

I am planning to rent a car at SF and drive over ~2 days to Grand Canyon (Norht Rim part of it).

What is the most scenic route? Is it interesting at all?? With 2 days to spare I want to do a couple of stops at some parks.

Or is it just better to fly to Flagstaff and rent a car there? And spend the saved time in the GC itself?

Comment: Flagstaff's airport is small, and closest to the south rim. For the north rim, fly into Las Vegas.

Comment: The fastest route is via I-5, Las Vegas, and St. George, Utah. I don't like Las Vegas. The scenery in Utah and Arizona is good. If you know what to look for, the polygamous radical Mormon sects are near St. George and you can see the families shopping. We're talking two full days of driving. If it were scenic, you wouldn't have much time to look anyway.